# Recursive function that removes all odd numbers in a string; how to include negative symbol

Tags: python, string, function, if-statement, recursion

Basically what the title says. It takes a string, removes all odd numbers in the string via recursion, and returns a modified string. For example, "54364" becomes "464", "4234" becomes "424", etc.

```
def removeOddDigits(inString):
#base case
    if inString == "":
        return inString
    else:
#if it's an even number keep it
        if int(inString[0]) % 2 == 0:
            return str(inString[0]) + str(removeOddDigits(inString[1:]))
        else:
#if it's an odd number skip it
            return removeOddDigits(inString[1:])
        
        
print(removeOddDigits(input("Enter String:")))
```

For the most part the code works as suspected, but I also want it to also include negative numbers. The problem is that it's only comparing int values, and the "-" character results in an invalid literal error. And I cannot use type() != int comparison either because it's all consisted of strings. Is there a way to bypass this so that it not only keeps even digits but also non-numerical characters?

Comment: What output do you want for `"24-61-35---72"`?  Would that be invalid input?  Is a `"-"` only allowed at the start of the string?  Are non-digit characters allowed (other than `"-"`)?

Comment: To keep it less complicated I will allow all non-numerical symbols. As for the first comment above, I want something that goes from "-123" to "-2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to remove all single digit numbers where "single digit number" could include something like `"-5"`. Instead of taking the first character from the string, you can take a substring of either 1 character or two depending on whether the string starts with `"-"`. You can take advantage of the fact that booleans act like `1` or `0` depending on the value to simplify things:

```
def removeOddDigits(inString):
    if inString == "":
        return inString

    s_length = inString.startswith('-') + 1
    n = int(inString[0: s_length])
    
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return str(n) + removeOddDigits(inString[s_length:])
    else:
        return removeOddDigits(inString[s_length:])

removeOddDigits("1-234567-89")
# '-246-8'
```

This will raise a `ValueError` for just `"-"`, which seems correct, but easily adjustable.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand this correctly, you are trying to keep every non-numerical, including `-`, unless it is in front of an odd number?

You could just add another if statement where you check if the next character is a number, and if not, if it is a `-` followed by a number, where you would check if it is odd, just like you did before.

I changed your code to do this, so for example `abc123-1-2-3` would result in `abc2-2`.

```py
def remove_odd_digits(in_string):
    # base case
    if in_string == "":
        return in_string
    else:
        # check if the next character is a number or not
        if in_string[0].isdecimal():
            # if it's an even number keep it
            if int(in_string[0]) % 2 == 0:
                return in_string[0] + remove_odd_digits(in_string[1:])
            else:
                # if it's an odd number skip it
                return remove_odd_digits(in_string[1:])
        # check if the next character is a - followed by a number
        elif (len(in_string) > 1 and in_string[0] == "-"
              and in_string[1].isdecimal()):
            # if it's an even number keep it
            if int(in_string[1]) % 2 == 0:
                return in_string[:2] + remove_odd_digits(in_string[2:])
            else:
                # if it's an odd number skip it
                return remove_odd_digits(in_string[2:])
        # if the next character is not a number keep it
        else:
            return in_string[0] + remove_odd_digits(in_string[1:])


print(remove_odd_digits(input("Enter String:")))
```

Also note, that in Python you normally don't use mixed case for function and variable names, like in your example, but lower case with underscores. So `removeOddDigits` would be `remove_odd_digits`.

You can find more on that in the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)

> Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.
> Variable names follow the same convention as function names.
> mixedCase is allowed only in contexts where that's already the prevailing style (e.g. threading.py), to retain backwards compatibility.